# Place two separate javascript slideshows on one page

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I'm learning javascript and one of my home works is to have two separate javascript slideshows on one page. I have been able to successful create the first slideshow. However, when I try to replicate the code and simply swap out the images, one slideshow stops. Here's the code for the first slideshow. Thanks for any help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var image1=new Image()
image1.src="../skin/frontend/default/pique/images/plans/deluxe/deluxe1.png"
var image2=new Image()
image2.src="../skin/frontend/default/pique/images/plans/deluxe/deluxe2.png"
var image3=new Image()
image3.src="../skin/frontend/default/pique/images/plans/deluxe/deluxe3.png"
//-->
</script>
<img src="../skin/frontend/default/pique/images/plans/deluxe/deluxe1.png" name="deluxe"
width="168" height="207" />
<script>
<!--
//variable that will increment through the images
var step=1
function slideit(){
//if browser does not support the image object, exit.
if (!document.images)
return
document.images.deluxe.src=eval("image"+step+".src")
if (step<3)
step++
else
step=1
//call function "slideit()" every 2.5 seconds
setTimeout("slideit()",2500)
}
slideit()
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Kaidul, I had a small problem with the code editor. It should be fixed now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the second slideshow use a separate name for the image like "deluxe_second" or anything and also define another slideit() function all the same excepting:

```
document.images.deluxe_second.src=eval("image"+step+".src")
```

Hope it will fix your problem :)